# how to PUT a "WrappedRequest" request for wcf RESTful service from Fiddler

Tags: c#, wcf-rest

I got the below REST service, I need to test it from fiddler, and I've searched alot, I figured how the payload is structured like the below:

```
<Update xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <value></value>
</Update>
```

"value" can be `XElement` or `IEnumerable<XElement>` and nothing else.

the above XML is okay (means it hits a break point with empty pure object instance passed) but if I put "anything" inside  node, I get 400 Bad Request without hitting any of my break points.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT", UriTemplate = "/{key}", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    void Update(string key, object value);

    [WebInvoke(Method = "DELETE", UriTemplate = "/{key}")]
    void Delete(string key);        
}

public void Update(string key, object value)
{
    this.UpdateSomething(key, value, true);
}
```

The question is how to create a proper xml to pass it to the service with Fiddler?

Answer (score 0):

creating a template xml from the schema (if you are using any) used by your server-side component is a good start.
other wise , you can compose a simple xml with all the attributes you are extracting at the Service(manual and error prone)

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm expecting XElement or array of XElements, so no xml template of any kind. Also I don't get any help from the service help page because the schema cannot be inferred at this point because of the WrappedRequest attrib.  I basically need to pass a flat xml in the form or key value pair in a form of XElement(s).

Answer (score -1):

Try `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare`